# Как спарсить сайт

Tags: php, html, парсер

Как спарсить с сайта Загаловок,Картинку,контент?

Чум лучше пользоватся какой самый быстрый?...

Answer (score 3):

Лично я пользовался библиотекой [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Довольно мощный инструмент.

Может и подойти встроенная в PHP [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) библотека, но необходимо иметь в виду что она будет рассматривать HTML как XML.

В качестве быстродействия PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser сжирает много памяти особенно если код будет слишком громоздким, но он по функционалу и качеству парсинга намного круче чем DomDocument. DomDocument можно использовать для парсинга тех HTML документов которые содержат мало ошибок или исключений из XML.

Comment: Добавлю к ответу https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/ Использовал этот инструмент, весьма успешно парсил больше количество данных. Перед парсингом советую пройтись http://htmlpurifier.org/ К сожалению, входящие данные не всегда валидные.

Comment: Я читал про http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ даже пробовал установить не почему то немогу...

Comment: Можете скинуть пример?.Я пробовал получал ошибку страницы

Comment: Почему не получается - уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Помнится партнёрам было лень сделать RSS-ленту на курсы валют, из-за этого мне пришлось парсить html-страницу, так как курсы обновлялись каждый час. Кидаю ссылку на инструмент которым пользовался для решения задачи.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://google.kz');
foreach($html->find('что тебе надо найти') as $e){
$arr[] = trim($e->innertext); //можно не массивом
}
print_r($arr); //пример вывода массива
?>
```

Comment: Кармы не хватает чтобы написать коммент другим. Перед функцией парса добавь `@`, это поможет проигнорировать ошибки на html-странице. На счёт установки, там всего 1 php-страница, её нужно скопировать в папку сайта, а потом добавить вначале посредством `include('simple_html_dom.php')`. Дальше по документации.

Comment: file_get_html('http://www.google.com/'); Пример такой функции вообщем нету есть file_get_contents

Comment: Вставь файл simple_html_dom.php в ту же директорию что и index.php. Пример вложу в ответ.

Comment: @Sauron она есть в `simple_html_dom.php`