# Защита от php curl

Tags: php, javascript

С помощью javascript генерирую число отправляю на сервер, можно ли как-то избежать того, что человек может отправить запрос с помощью curl(отправит другое число). То есть я хочу что бы число было именно то, которое генерируется с помощью javascript! Есть ли решения?

Comment: На клиенте понадобится какое-то секретное слово (пароль), которым можно подписать (или зашифровать) ваше число и проверить на сервере.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian так клиент может посмотреть это секретное слово в браузере через режим разработчика к примеру и отослать его тоже в месте с числом..

Comment: А, ну если клиент у вас не доверенное лицо, то вариантов увы нет. Разве что как-то обфусцировать, но это до поры до времени.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian обфускация тоже не вариант, то есть никак? ппц

Comment: Может тогда лучше на сервере это число генерировать?

Comment: Это число результат действий на стороне клиента на сервере не получится...

Comment: Если число зависит **только** от действий клиента, то вообще никак, т. к. вы ему в первую очередь доверили генерацию этого числа.

Answer (score 1):

Любые данные, которые создает, хранит и отправляет клиентская сторона (в данном случае барузер) могут быть отправлены на сервер с помощью Curl. Можно применить динамические имена переменных для данных, csrf защиту, обусфакцию кода, который отправляет данные и генерирует их, но не существует решений, которые будут гарантировать получение от клиентской стороны 100% ожидаемых данных. Любая обусфакция может быть подвергнута деобусфакции, любой алгоритм защиты или шифрования может быть разгадан.

Применяемые методы будут работать только в том случае, если затраты времени и уровень знаний злоумышенника сопоставим с ценностью полученных данных или нанесенным уроном в результате отправки данных, отличных от ожидаемых.

Попробуйте переосмыслить задачу и выполить ее на серверной стороне, например.

Comment: Для конкретных предложений защиты расскажите подробнее о выполняемой задаче.

Comment: Как пример: допустим человек вводит текст с клавиатуры в течении 1 минуты, получили число - скорость ввода. Как такую задачу решить на серверной стороне? =)

Comment: На keyDown отправлять ajax запрос и считать количество нажатий в секунду на серверной стороне. Либо вообще использовать websocket и отправлять нажатые клавиши прямо на сервер

Comment: Человек с помощью curl просто отправит запросы (как будто человек нажал keyDown) и все, ваше решение провалилось...

Comment: Задача изначально не имеет решения в таком виде.

Answer (score -1):

Защищаться бесполезно. Если хотим спарсить сайт, то приходим на Stack Overflow по-русски, задаем неграмотный вопрос [Как спарсить с сайта Загаловок,Картинку,контент? Чум лучше пользоватся какой самый быстрый?...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536880/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) и сразу получаем кучу ответов от жадных до репы доброхотов.

Так что решение тут только одно - старая добрая капча, причем такая, которую человек не с первого раза разгадает. Опять же, все благодаря доброхотам, которые радостно помогают школоте.

Comment: Тут, похоже, клавогонки изобретают, а не защищают контент.

Comment: @ilyaplot Вы хотели, пример я вам его предоставил, причем тут клавагонки? Или вы не можете смерится с тем, что не нашли решения и теперь обузите...

Comment: @user3737786 да не трогайте его, он не адекватный)) бегает по статьям и умничает

Comment: @user3737786 Однако, мой ответ пока лидирует по оценкам пользователей. Меня не смущает отсутствие решение текущего вопроса. А клавогонки - это проект, в котором, скорее всего, реализована какая-то защита. Рекомендую посмотреть как.

Answer (score -1):

1. простой способ генерите случайное числовое значение которое пишите в сесию отдаёте на фронт. После к этому числу прибовляем то которое получилось и отправляем сумму аяксом, на серваке проверяем сумму. Если разница грубо находиться в не ожидаемом диапозоне. Простой способ и просто обойти.
2. Одно разовый буквеный ключ(генерируемый на сервере) + метод шиврования (допустим буквы в ключе означают офсет, и если прибавить этот офсет к числу то получиться ещё один офсет который транспанируеться опятьже в буквенно числовой код) после хэшь отправляеться на бэкэнд где и проходит раскодировка кэша в обратное значение. Более надёжный и в принципе способ прост.
3. scrf вместе с числом отправлять ключ вместе с числом.
4. ещё один простой способ отправлять отпечаток времени вместе с числом, если разница во времени отправки не вписываеться в какой то промежуток времени то по бороде его.

Comment: Я признателен за ответ, но это все не катит и легко подделывается...